# How to make Eclipse with to report error when declared exception is not caught?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

How to make Eclipse to report error when declared exception is not caught? 
For example, if I declare method as

```
public int someMethod(int a, int b) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    ...
}
```

And then use it in another method like

```
public int anotherMethod() {
    ...
    return someMethod(a, b);
}
```

I want compiler to report error in anotherMethod, until I will catch IllegalArgumentException or declare another method as

```
public int anotherMethod() throws IllegalArgumentException {}
```

Comment: So you basically want your compiler to insert a try/catch which prints the stack trace in the catch block until you declare it otherwise manually? That's not possible in plain Java with default JDK. There might be a framework or alternative compiler but I don't think so.

Comment: my eclipse version reports this error but i have never changed some preferences.

Comment: Eclipse *does* report uncaught checked exceptions. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @thkala may be that's android plugin problem then... still error is definitely not reported

Comment: @kai see my comment above

Comment: @Natalia: perhaps you are expecting Eclipse to report an unchecked exception?

Comment: @Natalia now I get it. Totally missunderstood your question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse should actually report an error because you have an uncaught IOException in anotherMethod():

```
Unhandled exception type IOException
```

Only an unchecked exception (e.g. a RuntimeException) would cause the behaviour you are describing, but an IOException is a checked exception.

Maybe you have turned off error reporting in eclipse, but I doubt so. You can check this in Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors / Annotations / Errors. make sure all checkboxes are checked.

*Note: My answer refers to the original question asked before it was edited, which mentioned an IOException instead of an IllegalArgumentException.*

Comment: yes, I double checked and that is RuntimeException which is not reported... So I can't change that, because it's _runtime_?

Comment: @Natalia see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162572/eclipse-warn-about-uncaught-error

Comment: @Natalia: `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception, much like `Error` throwables. You can catch them, but the compiler will not complain if you do not because they are normally thrown for situations that the caller is not expected to or even unable to handle...

Comment: @Natalia see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963319/whats-the-configuration-to-notify-the-unhandled-exceptions-in-eclipse for more details