# Eclipse doesn't report error for uncaught exception

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I use sts-3.5.0.M1 for developing and I encounter that eclipse doesn't report any error or warning for uncaught exception, how can I force eclipse to do this job?

My question is the same as 
[How to make Eclipse with to report error when declared exception is not caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038779/how-to-make-eclipse-with-to-report-error-when-declared-exception-is-not-caught)
but it doesn't help me?

Thanks

Comment: What exception is it not reporting?

Comment: You can see the complete question in above URL.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is an [unchecked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) which doesn't have to be caught and Eclipse won't warn about.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wonder that is it possible to put this exception to checked exception and Eclipse warn about it.

Comment: No this can't be changed. If this is your code create an exception derived from `Exception` - this will be checked.