# Java/Eclipse: Why some throws are ignored by the IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, warnings

Namely any `enum` `valueof()` (not the class `Enum`) will not require try/catch for `IllegalArgumentException`.

I had to look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf), and at the `Enum` class, to know about it.

As a bonus answer, I would like to know if there is some way to make the IDE require these try/catch blocks. Namely Eclipse IDE.

PS.: I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, an upgrade suggestion is acceptable also.

Comment: Your *asking for bonus* made me laugh :)

Comment: @Shadowfax good, you at least are more happier than me concerning this problem :)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The first bit is an obvious duplicate, but the bonus (can I get my IDE to force me to put try/catch blocks for unchecked exceptions) might not be.

Comment: @PaulBoddington excellent thx! I think this is a double duplicate then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963319/whats-the-configuration-to-notify-the-unhandled-exceptions-in-eclipse, and now I have my answer :)